# Create a file to read server url for api in vue js after production build

Tags: vue.js

I am new to vue js . I have multiple servers for api calls. I am using vue js for frontend but the problem is when i build the app for production vue is not giving me any static config file so where i can replace  my server url for api calls  without re build the vue app for each server.I just want to replace the url to work on same production app for all server without build for each.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating  JSON file in public folder e.g Server_config.JSON file in public folder and added my server ip address and imported that json file into my project from there after production  build i can easily change the server ips.